# Template NullObject: Is it a sin?

Tags: java, null, null-object-pattern

I coded this little Template-NullObject in Java and wanted to ask you wether it would be considered a sin to use one of these.
When creating a NullObject, you typically make one which was specifically designed for one type of object, this one isn't ...

```
public class NullObject<T> {

    T object;

    public NullObject(T object) {
        this.object = object;
    }

    public T get() {
        return object;
    }

    public void set(T object) {
        this.object = object;
    }

    public boolean isNull() {
        return object == null;
    }

}
```

Comment: It's fine if that's what you need. There's also `Optional<>`, but that is immutable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's OK. But I think you're reinventing the wheel, you may check for Optional in java 8 : [Optional in Java 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java8-optional-2175753.html). It's easy to work with and makes your code clearer.

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot, sir. There's only one problem, I can't seem to find the com.google.common library inside the JRE library which makes it impossible for me to add javadocs to it via Eclipse. Do you happen to know anything about the positioning of Optional<T> and other google.common classes?

Comment: Well I think it is Java 8 SDK standard libraries? Just get JDK 8.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the above, if you're using Java 7 or earlier, you can import Guava, and use the Optional<> class there.